# ruby on rails form params becomes null on update action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I just started learning rails. I'm trying to create a page to display comments/contents as well as adding comments.
This is what my update controller looks like:

```
  def update_memo
    @article = Article.find_by_id(params[:id])
    @article.update_attributes(:memo => params[:remark])
    redirect_to :back
  end
```

And this is what my form looks like:

```
<%= form_for @article.memo, url: {action: "update_memo", id: @article.id},  html: {method: "put"} do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :'Comment:' %>
  <%= f.text_field :remark %>
  <%= f.submit "Save !"%>
<%  end %>
```

It was fine when I update the memo field for the first time. But when I try to update again. It shows "Mysql2::Error: Column 'memo' cannot be null"

```
Started PUT "/showarticle/update_memo?id=1" 
Processing by ShowarticleController#update_memo as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"‚ì", "authenticity_token"=>"LXEUxk>wI9W+VpAP+mpULojiGeYTDoSBIjrCkkA3GacYwZLZyJyfHFOsoxwdSS5LUoQDuP3FGidopp2KA==", "test1"=>{"remark"=>"test0"}, "commit"=>"Save !", "id"=>"1"}
Article Load (1.8ms)  SELECT  `articles`.* FROM `articles` WHERE `articles`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
   (1.5ms)  BEGIN
SQL (3.5ms)  UPDATE `articles` SET `memo` = NULL WHERE `articles`.`id` = 1
Mysql2::Error: Column 'memo' cannot be null: UPDATE `articles` SET `memo` = NULL WHERE `articles`.`id` = 1
   (1.5ms)  ROLLBACK
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 14ms (ActiveRecord: 8.3ms)
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass article object to form_for helper:

```
<%= form_for @article, url: {action: "update_memo", id: @article.id},  html: {method: "put"} do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :'Comment:' %>
  <%= f.text_field :memo %>
  <%= f.submit "Save !"%>
<%  end %>
```

Your controller's action:

```
def update_memo
  @article = Article.find_by_id(params[:id])
  @article.update_attributes(:memo => params][:article][:memo])
  redirect_to :back
end
```

And I recomend you to read about strong_parameters(http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html)

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :articles do
   resources :memos #-> url.com/articles/:article_id/memos/new
end

#app/controllers/memos_controller.rb
class MemosController < ApplicationController
   def new
      @article = Article.find params[:article_id]
      @memo = @article.memos.new
   end

   def create
      @article = Article.find params[:article_id]
      @memo = @article.memos.new memo_params
      @memo.save
   end

   private

   def memo_params
      params.require(:memo).permit(:article_id, :remark)
   end
end

#app/views/memos/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @memo do |f| %>
   <%= f.text_field :remark %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```